# How can I pull the Wikidata description?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm trying to pull the wikidata description of biblical figures.
For example, for [David](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q41370), this would pull: `king of Israel and Judah`.

Here's what I started with:

```
select ?person ?personLabel
where {
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q20643955.
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikidata Query Service/User Manual § Label_service](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual#Label_service):

> You can fetch the label, alias, or description [...] In automatic mode, you only need to specify the service template, e.g.:
>
> ```
> PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
> SERVICE wikibase:label {
>     bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
> }
> ```
>
> and WDQS will automatically generate labels as follows:
>
> - If an unbound variable in `SELECT` is named `?NAMELabel`, then WDQS produces the label (`rdfs:label`) for the entity in variable `?NAME`.
> - If an unbound variable in `SELECT` is named `?NAMEAltLabel`, then WDQS produces the alias (`skos:altLabel`) for the entity in variable
>   `?NAME`.
> - If an unbound variable in `SELECT` is named `?NAMEDescription`, then WDQS produces the description (`schema:description`) for the
>   entity in variable `?NAME`.

So you can just specify `?personDescription` among your selected variables.

[Here](https://query.wikidata.org/#select%20%3Fperson%20%3FpersonLabel%20%3FpersonDescription%0Awhere%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ20643955.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D) an example.